# How to enforce class to have only interface parameters

Tags: typescript

enforce class A to have only interface parameter *name only*

```
interface I {
name: string;
}

Class A implements I{
name: string;
age: string; <=  it should generate error 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? A class can implement multiple interfaces, and have other props on top of that.

Comment: I am using multiple models like for backend and multiple frontends that is why I want to strict the schema for everyone

Comment: That's not really an explanation. If you access them via the interface you can only use the props defined on that interface anyway.

Comment: is there any other way to strict the class to have only those props which have defined for that?

Comment: It's really not clear why you still think you want this, but to be explicit: no.

Comment: the problem is whenever I changed in one model I forgot to change in another  that is why I was thinking to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this, but you can use a [recursively bounded type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) to get the desired behavior, as long as you're willing to mention the class name twice in your definition:

```
type Exactly<T, U extends T> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never }

class A implements Exactly<I, A> {
    name: string = "needs initialization";
    age: string = "me too" // error!
//  ~~~ <--- string is not assignable to never
}
```

The type `Exactly<T, U>` is a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type with [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) properties.  The output of `Exactly<T, U>` has all the same keys as `U`, but the values for any keys no in `T` are of type `never`.

The constraint `U extends T` means that `U` must have *at least* all the properties of `T`. And the constraint in `class U implements Exactly<T, U>` means that `U` must not have any defined properties not found in `T`, or else `U` could not match `Exactly<T, U>`.

In the above code example, `A` is something like `{name: string, age: number}`.  And `Exactly<I, A>` evaluates to `{name: string, age: never}`.  So the constraint `class A implements Exactly<I, A>` is not met, because `{name: string, age: number}` does not implement`{name: string, age: never}`.  The problem is in the `age` property, so you get an error where you want it.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4Chm+SOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfZLLMATwAcUBRAD0RgANuwA8AFQA0yAKrIIfSCAAm5ZOIB8yALyZkAbQDSyUMgDWEdgHsYsgLpljCpavOWb65AH51Ru8jIQCAA3aGRGVgQhOHI1AEETQk4hCGJwNX5BEVFUaTitbDx8IlIKKlodZAAiIIhXUGAwYDghYAAvOCarECqGIrgaUspqEBpKquJkMCsrKuQAenn5KCgrKABCLEXcAD895FEAWmOykbHgNRArMGQY8mAaAgAjFKmrfBDoJiA)